# Pictures "from" or "of" the adventure?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

So which one is correct if someone just came from an adventure:

1. "Any pictures **from** the adventure?"
2. "Any pictures **of** the adventure?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use either.  The difference between the two is very subtle.

I'm not sure I can justify this, but I feel as though pictures *from* the adventure would be pictures that I, who took the adventure, had taken (or that one of my adventure companions had taken), whereas pictures *of* the adventure could have been taken by outsiders witnessing our adventure, and we happened somehow to get copies of the photos.  I'm not sure people give such thought to choosing the preposition here, however.